# Creation of Contract using C#asp.net in MS CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

[image]

> Error Details :=> An exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException' occurred in Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The content type text/html; charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 1024 bytes of the response were:
>
> ```
> '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
>
> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
>
> <head> 
>
> <title>IIS 7.5 Detailed Error - 500.19 - Internal Server Error</title> 
>
> <style type="text/css"> 
>
> <!-- 
>
> body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;background:#CBE1EF;}
>
>
> code{margin:0;color:#006600;font-size:1.1em;font-weight:bold;} 
>
> .config_source code{font-size:.8em;color:#000000;} 
>
> pre{margin:0;font-size:1.4em;word-wrap:break-word;} 
>
> ul,ol{margin:10px 0 10px 40px;} 
>
> ul.first,ol.first{margin-top:5px;} 
>
> fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} 
>
> .summary-container fieldset{padding-bottom:5px;margin-top:4px;} 
>
> legend.no-expand-all{padding:2px 15px 4px 10px;margin:0 0 0 -12px;} 
>
> legend{color:#333333;padding:4px 15px 4px 10px;margin:4px 0 8px -12px;_margin-top:0px; 
>
>  border-top:1px solid #EDEDED;border-left:1px solid #EDEDED;border-right:1px solid #969696; 
>
>  border-bottom:1px solid #969696;background:#E7ECF0;font-weight:bold;'.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line `attach.Id = id_attach;`, you should not pass primary key when you create a new record.